# How to pin each instance to a processor on remote hosts using gnu parallel

Tags: gnu-parallel, taskset

I'm using gnu parallel to run many instances of an executable in batches. Each instance must be pinned to its own processor. On a single local host, this is straightforward; I set the number of slots to be the number of processors, then do:

`taskset -c $(( {%} - 1)) ...`

I'm not sure how to extend this to multiple hosts over ssh, since the slot index can no longer easily translate to a processor index.

One idea: my nodes all have the same number of processors, so if the slots could be initially assigned contiguously, filling up each node before any are assigned to the next, I could calculate a processor index from the slot index. However, it seems that slots are assigned in a round-robin fashion, and I haven't been able to figure out how to change that.

Any ideas on how I can get this to work? Thanks

Comment: I am curious why you need to pin a job to a CPU. Can you elaborate on why that is needed?

Comment: Sure; each job runs a simulation, and each simulation spawns a number of threads. I'd like to keep a single simulation confined to one CPU. Part of that is for housekeeping (I tend to saturate the nodes, so that every CPU is running at 100%, and it's cleaner to have all the threads for a given simulation reside next to each other). Perhaps the more important reason is memory locality; the physical nodes have two NUMA nodes each, and I don't want separate threads from the same simulation to end up on different NUMA nodes where the memory access times may be affected.